# ¿Como instalo librerías de python en MacOS?

Tags: python-3.x

he intentado instalar librerías de python en MacOS Mojave para python 3.7. Las instalo desde la terminal con el comando pip y según esto se instala, incluso cuando uso pip list me aparece en la lista de librerías, pero cuando intento importarla desde el IDE de python me dice que no tengo esa librería instalada.
Gracias !

He intentado instalar : colorama y matplotlib

Comment: Ayudaría mucho que por ejemplo indiques ¿cuáles son esas librerías?, para que la comunidad pueda identificar mas rápido que ocurre

Comment: Si tienes más de un intérprete instalado `pip` instala las librerías solo en el intérprete al que está asociado. Tienes que asegurarte de instalar las librerías en el mismo intérprete o entorno que usas en tu IDE. Puedes ver la ruta del mismo si haces `import sys;print(sys.executable)`.

Comment: FJSevilla, ¿Cómo especifico  en que interprete quiero  que se instale la librería  ? Gracias

Comment: Que IDE tienes?

Comment: Una opción general es que obtengas la ruta de `import sys;print(sys.executable)` en tu IDE y uses pip como módulo: ``ruta\al\intérprete -m pip install colorama`` (en la terminal). Existen muchas formas, pero necesitamos más información como las versiones  instaladas (puede que tengas instalados Python 2 y Python 3), cual es la que usa tu sistema por defecto (ingresa `python` en la terminal y mira el intérprete que se ejecuta), cual usas en tu IDE, el IDE mismo que usas como comenta Sr1871 (algunos tiene gestores de paquetes incorporados como PyCharm), etc

Comment: Mi sistema operativo usa Python 2.7.10, parece que tengo Python 2 y Python 3, tengo el IDE que descargas en la pagina de python, tengo el visual studio code y ademas tengo instalado Anaconda para usar Spyder

Comment: En todos los IDE se supone que uso python 3.7

Comment: Puedes hacer `python3 -m pip install colorama` o si tienes pip3: `pip3 install colorama`.  Si tienes Anaconda instalado  puedes usar `conda install colorama` o usar anaconda navigator para instalar paquetes gráficamente: https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/tasks/install-packages/

Comment: Gracias ! Creo que lo he logrado, de mínimo en el IDE oficial de python aunque no logro hacerlo funcionar en Visual Studio

Comment: El problema es que tienes instaladas dos versiones de python: la 2.7 y la 3... Estás instalando librerías para la 2.7 y cuando las pides desde python3 no las encuentra